# Why $V_{ij} = \frac {1}{2}(v_iv_j^T + v_jv_i^T),$ is rank-2 if $i\neq j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone help me figure out the following argument ?

$V_{ij} = \frac {1}{2}(v_iv_j^T + v_jv_i^T),$ is rank-2 if $i\neq j$ where $v_i,v_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v_i,v_j$ are linearly indepedent.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what the condition $i\neq j$ implies. Does this mean that $v_i$ and $v_j$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, It is linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** The matrix $V$ can be written as a product of two rank-two matrices (or three if you want a "symmetric" product):
$$
V=\frac{1}{2}(vw^T+wv^T)=\frac{1}{2}[v,w][w,v]^T=\frac{1}{2}[v,w]\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}[v,w]^T.
$$

Comment: Good. I can understand your meaning. One basic question,$[v, w]$ is $2n\times 2$, $[v,w]^T$ is $2\times 2n$, so the result is  $2n \times 2n$ matrix, so the expression might be wrong.

Comment: @guanlei Nope. $[v,w]$ is $n\times 2$ and $[w,v]^T$ is $2\times n$.

Comment: Are we sure that rank never decreases with multiplication? Doesn't sound reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

So suppose that $v,w \in \mathbb R^n$ are linearly independent. Then the matrix
$$
M:={v^T\choose w^T} \in \mathbb R^{2\times n}
$$
has rank $2$. This means there are $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
Mx = {1\choose 0}\qquad and \qquad My = {0\choose 1},
$$
or more explicitly
$$
v^Tx = 1,\quad w^Tx = 0,\quad v^Ty = 0,\quad w^Ty = 1.
$$
Now we put
$$
A:= vw^T+wv^T \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.
$$
For any $z\in \mathbb R^n,$we have
$$
Az = vw^Tz + wv^Tz = v(w^Tz)+w(v^Tz) \in \mathbb R v + \mathbb R w.
$$
This shows that the image of $A$ is contained in the span of $v$ and $w$ - in symbols
$$
im\ A \subseteq \mathbb R v + \mathbb R w.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
Ax = vw^Tx+wv^Tx = w\qquad and \qquad Ay = vw^Ty+wv^Ty = v.
$$
This shows that
$$
\mathbb R v + \mathbb R w \subseteq im\ A.
$$
All in all, we must have equality:
$$
im\ A = \mathbb R v + \mathbb R w.
$$
Here, the r.h.s has dimension $2,$ since $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent. So we conclude
$$
rank\ A = \dim im\ A = 2.
$$
This answers your question.

Comment: Very clear ! Thanks very much,jflipp.